# Prove that $\nu$ is an outer measure

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\eta: P(\mathbb{R}) \to [0,\infty]$  be an arbitrary function with $\eta(\emptyset)=0$, where $P(\mathbb{R})=\{A: A \subset (-\infty,\infty)\}$. For $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ (i.e. $A \subset (-\infty,\infty))$, define

$$\nu(A)=\inf \{ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \eta(A_{i}) : A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i}\}$$

Prove that $\nu$ is an outer measure and $\nu \leq \eta$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\{A_i\}$ is any finite or countably infinite family of sets whose union contains $A$ by definition you have $$\nu(A) \le \sum_i \eta(A_i).$$ Since $A \subset A$ it follows that $\nu(A) \le \eta(A)$.

A simple consequence of this is that $\nu(\emptyset) = 0$. It remains to show that $\nu$ is countably subadditive: if $\{B_n\}$ is a countable family of subsets of $\mathbb R$ then $$\nu \left( \bigcup_n B_n \right) \le \sum_n \nu(B_n).$$ If the sum on the right is infinite there is nothing to show, so assume without loss of generality that $\nu(B_n) < \infty$ for all $n$. Fix $\epsilon > 0$ and for each $n$ select a sequence $\{A_i^n\}$ of subsets of $\mathbb R$ whose union contains $B_n$ and that satisfies
$$ \sum_i \eta(A_i^n) < \mu(B_n) + \frac{\epsilon}{2^n}.$$ The union of the countable family $\{A_i^n\}$ contains the union of the $B_n$ so that
$$
\nu \left( \bigcup_n B_n \right) \le \sum_{i,n} \eta(A_i^n) \le \sum_n \nu(B_n) + \epsilon.$$ Now let $\epsilon \to 0$.